# Iterating a list of dictionaries and creating a result set by comparing two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

We have two lists in the below format:

```
list_A = [
    {u'salary': 11, u'id': 1, u'name': u'adam'},
    {u'salary': 22, u'id': 2, u'name': u'ben'},
    {u'salary': 33, u'id': 3, u'name': u'charles'}
]

list_B = [
    {u'salary': 101, u'id': 1, u'name': u'adam'},
    {u'salary': 44, u'id': 4, u'name': u'david'}
]
```

How do I get id if common in both, then select from list B?

```
res = [
    {u'salary': 101, u'id': 1, u'name': u'adam'},
    {u'salary': 22, u'id': 2, u'name': u'ben'},
    {u'salary': 33, u'id': 3, u'name': u'charles'},
    {u'salary': 44, u'id': 4, u'name': u'david'}
]
```

I tried a `for` loop iterating on list A checking element in B and appending to empty list `res`, but was not able to achieve the desired result.

id is unique element.
list A is old , list B is new, so we have to append the list B to list A overwriting the other elements , in this case, salary is updated for Adam.

Comment: Shouldn't your result list only have Adam?

Comment: Are your `id` values *unique* in either list? Then just convert your lists to dictionaries.

Comment: no, the goal here is - list A is old , list B is new, so we have to append the list B to list A overwriting the common elements , in this case, salary is updated for Adam,

Comment: yes, id is unique.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your data in a dictionary and use the [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method to make the necessary changes.

```
list_A = [
    {u'salary': 11, u'id': 1, u'name': u'adam'},
    {u'salary': 22, u'id': 2, u'name': u'ben'},
    {u'salary': 33, u'id': 3, u'name': u'charles'}
]

list_B = [
    {u'salary': 101, u'id': 1, u'name': u'adam'},
    {u'salary': 44, u'id': 4, u'name': u'david'}
]

data = {d['id']: d for d in list_A}
new_data = {d['id']: d for d in list_B}

data.update(new_data)

res = list(data.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionaries:

```
by_id = {d['id']: d for d in list_A}
by_id.update({d['id']: d for d in list_B})
```

You can avoid creating the second dictionary by using a lazy generator:

```
by_id.update((d['id'], d) for d in list_B)
```